# Preloader/Progress Bar in ListBox WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, progress-bar

I would like to add a preloader to a ListBox, I already added a preloader to the whole pivot control, but I only show it for one listbox (I have a listbox for each pivot page) I wish to create separate preloaders for each listbox, has any one done this?

I currently have a preloader control, showing the loading text and progress bar
Is there any way I can attach a progress bar to the listbox, and show it until the data is loaded from the webservice (For each different listbox)?

This is my current preloader:

[image]

code preview of my list in xaml

```xml
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" Name="listNearbyBusinesses" IsAsyncBalanceEnabled="True" AsyncBalanceMode="FillViewportFirst" SelectionChanged="listNearbyBusinesses_SelectionChanged" Height="535" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="100" Height="100" x:Name="m_Image" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                <StackPanel>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                    <telerikInput:RadRating  IsReadOnly="True" Value="{Binding Rating}" Margin="12" ItemShapeHeight="20" ItemShapeWidth="20" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

Comment: Could you include a simplified version of your XAML?

Comment: ok I will edit my post and insert the xaml on the post